# Running SQL Profiler in the background

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-profiler

I want to leave SQL Server profiler running all the time logging any query that runs for longer than 5 seconds. It's simple enough to start this using the profiler tool on my PC but how do I create it so it runs in the background on the server?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would recommend that you use a server side trace for this task rather than running a SQL Server Profiler trace via the GUI.

The performance overhead of running a server side trace, verses a trace via SQL Server Profiler is significantly reduced.

Take a look at the following blog post for an example of creating a server side trace:

- [SQL Server Performance Statistics
  Using a Server Side Trace](http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=1035)

For detailed documentation consult SQL Server Books Online topic:

- [Introducing SQL Trace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191006.aspx)